# is there a way to trigger 10 scripts at any given time in Linux shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a requirement where I need to trigger 10 shell scripts at a time.  I may have 200+ shell scripts to be executed.

e.g. if I trigger 10 jobs and two jobs completed, I need to trigger another 2 jobs which will make number of jobs currently executing to 10.

I need your help and suggestion to cater this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below to trigger 10 jobs a time.

```
max_jobs_trigger=10



while mapfile -t -n ${max_jobs_trigger} ary && ((${#ary[@]})); do
    jobs_to_trigger=`printf '%s\n' "${ary[@]}"`

#Trigger script in background

done
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel -j 10 < ListOfJobs.txt
```

---

Or, if your jobs are called `job_1.sh` to `job_200.sh`:

```
parallel -j 10 job_{}.sh ::: {1..200}
```

---

Or. if your jobs are named with discontiguous, random names but are all shell scripts named with `.sh` suffix in one directory:

```
parallel -j 10 ::: *.sh
```

---

There is a very good overview [here](https://zenodo.org/record/1146014/files/GNU_Parallel_2018.pdf?download=1). There are lots of questions and answers on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-parallel).

Answer (score 1):

Simply run them as background jobs:

```
for i in {1..10}; { ./script.sh & }
```

Adding more jobs if less than 10 are running:

```
while true; do
    pids=($(jobs -pr))
    ((${#pids[@]}<10)) && ./script.sh &
done &> /dev/null
```

Comment: I tried this and it works. However consider i have 10 jobs and 2 jobs completed, i need to trigger 2 more jobs. I should have 10 jobs to be running at any given point of time.

Comment: @aks: With GNU `xargs`: `for i in {1..200}; do echo "$i"; done | xargs -P 10 -I {} bash -c "./script_{}.sh"` See: `man xargs`

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to handle this:

- Launch them together as background tasks (1)
- Launch them in parallel (1)
- Use the `crontab` (2)
- Use `at` (3)

Explanations:

(1) You can launch the processes exactly when you like (by launching a command, click a button or whatever event you choose)
(2) The processes will be launched at the same time, every (working) day, periodically.
(3) You choose a time when the processes will be launched together once.

Comment: I think the OP is being idiomatic and means *"all in parallel"* rather than meaning *"at some time on a clock on the wall"* in the sense of scheduling at some time of day. I may be wrong - I have been before ;-)